# ajax reading/getting variable sometimes cannot get the exact variable with codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am having a problem in my ajax or i don't know if it is a problem with ajax. I have an ajax code to get a value from label and concat it in my fresh data from database. Everytime i refresh the page, it outputs different. Sometimes it works fine, and sometimes it doesn't.

I am having my trouble in this part :

```
else {
              value = value + "-"+init;
              $('#checkID').text(value);
              $("#checkID").css('visibility','visible');
            }
```

sometimes it outputs 1-0 and sometimes the output became -0.
I am thinking of `var value = $('#clinicID').html();` cannot concat with my `-0` where the 1 of the output 1-0 is came from value variable

Here is my ajax full code :

```
function getcheckupID() {

var init = 0;
var value = $('#clinicID').html();

  $.ajax ({
    url: siteurl+"myclinic/getcheckID",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(data) {
        if(data.length>0) {

          $('#checkID').text(data[0]['check_up_id']);
          $("#checkID").css('visibility','visible');
        }
        else {
          value = value + "-"+init;
          $('#checkID').text(value);
          $("#checkID").css('visibility','visible');
        }
    }
  }) 
}
```

my document ready code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  get_clinicID();
  show_patients();
  checkupme();
});
```

where `checkupme()` function got a nested `getcheckupID()` runtime

Comment: It doesn't matter where a string comes from, it's just a string, and it can always be concatenated. What do you see if you do `console.log(value);` at the beginning of the function?

Comment: @Barmar thank you for your answer sir. Is this not an issue of ajax ?. slow down in concatinating ?

Comment: What does AJAX have to do with it? The `else` code doesn't use anything that came from the server, it's just concatenating two variables that it set normally.

Comment: yes sir.. there are no response from server, just concatting the two variables but why still i got not constant value. sometimes i got -0 and sometimes i got the exact which is 1-0

Comment: The only reason for that is that `$('#clinicID').html()` is returning an empty string.

Comment: How does `#clinicID` get filled in? Is it updated dynamically by some other asynchronous code?

Comment: it is updated using jquery sir. i got it from my DB. and put it in document.ready

Comment: Is it updated before or after you call `getcheckupID()`?

Comment: GET http://[::1]/clinic/myclinic/get_clinicID
 
200 OK
  52ms 
jquery-....min.js (line 4)

GET http://[::1]/clinic/myclinic/getcheckID
 
200 OK
  44ms

Comment: i got it from my console sir, but my question is, why sometimes its ok and sometimes refreshing again its not ?

Comment: I don't know, I'd have to see the whole code to understand. Use the Javascript debugger in your browser to trouble shoot it. Set a breakpoint in the function, and see what the value of `value` is.

Comment: sir @Barmar i put the #clinicID in document.ready function. Is it fired first ?

Comment: How do you call `getcheckID()`? Do you call it from `document.ready()` just like `getclinicID()`? You should call it from the callback function of `getclinicID()`, so that it doesn't run until after you've filled in `#clinicID`. If you start two AJAX functions, you can't guarantee that the callback functions will run in the same order that you start them.

Comment: lol thank you @Barmar i already got the problem. can you please input a formal answer. thank you sir.. you really save me.

Comment: @Barmar sir, one last question, do you think jquery/ajax can slow down my page ? i used jquery almost all of my request to DB in codeigniter.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it. The ease of programming that it allows makes up for the slight performance impact. So unless you're a good Javascript programmer (which you aren't), take the easy way.

Comment: You need to post the part of your document.ready that sets both `#clinicID` and `#checkID`, so I can write an answer that shows how to fix it.

Comment: @Barmar ok sir, i'll edit my question .. . Sir even if i have many data ? ajax/jquery is still not affecting my runtime ? or it will affect but would not lead to serious problem ?

Comment: Read this: [Premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization)

Answer (score 0):

I suggested another way to get data in `#clinicID` that you can use

When you refresh the page, insert your `#clinicID` like:

`<span id="clinicID" data-value="1-0"><span>` or whatever data you wanna input.

Then in `getcheckupID` function you'll call:

```
function getcheckupID() {
  var init = 0;
  var value = $('#clinicID').attr("data-value");
  // Your code ajax
}
```

If it still have problem, please check your `echo` when page generated. Maybe there're not any value to print.

Hope this help.